# How to copy cell values from WorkSheet1 to WorkSheet, aka, how to create a masterlist in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, rows

I am trying to create a master list of several excel data that I have. I have never worked with Excel + VBA programs/codes.

There are 2 columns in WorkSheet1. The Column1 is some sort of word(s), terminology and the Column2 holds the definition for Column1. Now, I have to copy the definition of that Column1 and put in the Column2(if empty, if not, then in Column3 or the next empty column) in WorkSheet2 right next to the corresponding Column1. Continue doing this for the rest of the Rows in WorkSheet1. Basically, there should not be any repetition of the same values. The Column1 in WorkSheet2 can have more than 1 definition Columns, as long as they are not the same.

Does this make sense? Is it possible to do something like this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to automate this? Is this something you're going to be doing multiple times?

Comment: Your description is not that clear - try putting some sample data ("before" and "after" of sheet2). To answer your question though - yes that is very possible.

Comment: Tmdean, yea, I would like to create something that is useful later on, too. Because, there will definitely be more stuff like this to do later. For this particular one, I want to automate it, because, it has about 2000 rows, and I am sure it will take me several hours to go through each one manually. Thanks.

Comment: @TimWilliams, sorry for the mess there, ha. I don't know how to attach a file here, but, thanks for the effort. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Excel VBA. If I understand your post correctly, this should give you (at the least basics of) what you are after. This may need to tweaking based on your specific workbook and data sets, but it will give you a **GREAT** start. There is a plethora of help available on all the methods / procedures I've used, and I've tried to comment well in English so you can understand what is happening.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveIt()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook 'change to your workbook reference

Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet
Set wks1 = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change to your name / definition sheet
Set wks2 = wkb.Sheets("Sheet2") 'change to the sheet where you need to paste defintions

With wks1

    Dim rngLoop As Range, cel As Range
    'assumes row 1 as column header, and definitions in Column B (2)
    Set rngLoop = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Columns(2)) 'basically all rows with definitions in Column 2

    For Each cel In rngLoop 'loop through each definition


        Dim rngFound As Range

        'look for associated definition name in 2nd sheet
        'assumes Name in Column 1 of both worksheets
        Set rngFound = wks2.Columns(1).Find(cel.Offset(, -1).Text, lookat:=xlWhole)


        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then 'if the name is found

            'look to see if defintion already exists in row aligned with Name of 2nd sheet
            Dim rngFoundAgain As Range
            Set rngFoundAgain = rngFound.EntireRow.Find(cel.Text,lookat:=xlWhole)

            'if not found
            If rngFoundAgain Is Nothing Then

                If rngFound.Offset(, 1) = vbNullString Then
                'if next cell (row of rngFound, column B) is blank

                    rngFound.Offset(, 1) = cel.Text

                Else
                'go the right most cell and place definition in next column

                    rngFound.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1) = cel.Text

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: does this code go under new Modules -> Module1 ? I am new to this, so, I don't know where to start from :) Sorry. And thanks!

Comment: Exactly. Place this code into a new Module (or any existing one), just not inside a worksheet module or this workbook module.

Comment: yes, I did a new insert -> module and put it in there. However, I am getting this "Runtime error '1004'. Application-defined or object-defined error" and when I press 'debug' it is pointing to this: 'rngFound.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1) = cel'   line

Comment: I just updated the code to solve for an issue I didn't foresee. Hence, you learned another important aspect of programming. Debugging support!

Comment: never mind. Fixed it :) Thanks for your help. It is not fully functional, but that problem is gone, haha. I will keep you posted.

Comment: great. Don't forget to mark the answer if you feel it's given you enough, so other users can benefit in the future.

Comment: it is working, partially :). This is AWESOME. I don't know how you do it! There is one question/problem though. Since, my Column A and Column B (might)contain long definitions/sentences, is there a way to grab the whole thing? AND compare the whole thing between the worksheets and not just the string(s) inside those sentences? Do I make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but what you are asking is already being done. It takes whatever is inside any given cell and compares it against all the cells in the matching row on the 2nd sheet. And just so you know for future reference, I basically wrote this code for you. Typically on SO, we answer Q's on specific coding problems when the user posts code and error descriptions. Just so you know that this is a "write my code for site." Since you were so new to VBA I thought it beneficial to give you something to learn from, work with."

Comment: thanks for all the help. Yes, it is doing what you said it does, but, I think, it is also thinking that the Name from WorkSheet 1 is the same as the Name from WorkSheet2 even if they are partially the same. Ex: Name1 = "OR/+"  Name2 = "Copay OR SPay" Those 2 have different definitions. However, it is pasting the definition of "OR/+" next to that wrong Name2 column in WorkSheet2. I am really sorry if I went way too far. I usually, never ask for step by step help. This is something that I am really new at. I really appreciate all of your effort though. Thank you very much!

Comment: ah! Yes, another bug, but yet again, a good learning experience. I just need to set the `.Find` property to look for the Whole value and not just part. Code in my answer is Edited for this.

Comment: there is another debug issue. Runtime error - Type mismatch. It is pointing to this line: 'Set rngFoundAgain = rngFound.EntireRow.Find(cel, lookat:=xlWhole)'  - When I hover the mouse over the "cel" variable, it is showing "cel = some value from one of my definition cells" What does that mean?

Comment: Change cel to cel.Value or cel.Text, Admittedly, I get a little lazy with this stuff at times :)

Comment: it is still doing the same. I think it is stuck at that row and can't move past it to process the next. I would not mind attaching some example from my excel sheet, but don't know how on SO.

Comment: you can post to wiki.send or some other site and then share the link so I can open the wkb

Comment: is there any book on/about Excel + VBA that you'd recommend to newbies like me? It seems like you have done your homework when it comes to stuff like this :)

Comment: I've been doing it for years. Google is a great resource to learn VBA these days. Walkenbach used to be the go to source (author) when I was learning. [This](www.ozgrid.com), [This](http://peltiertech.com/) and [This](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) are great sites.

Comment: @Scott, unfortunately my office comp. is not letting me through to any of those sites. I guess, I will have to get back to you later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, thanks to Scott.
If the cell holds more characters than Excel's standard max. then plug in this code instead of this line of code inside the first "If NOT..." statement `Set rngFoundAgain = rngFound.EntireRow.Find(cel.Text,lookat:=xlWhole)` plug in this line:

```
Set rngFoundAgain = rngFound.EntireRow.Find(Left(cel.Value, 255), lookat:=xlWhole)
```